# MVC ModelState Remove keys when deleting item in a list model

Tags: list, model-view-controller, modelstate

In an MVC View when a user deletes an item in a list (e.g. using an Edit Template), an associated action may be used to remove that item from the view model. However, the item may still show in the re-rendered view. Even if the view contains one less item, the wrong item may be have been removed from the displayed items.

Because ModelState is the first choice [before the (view) model] for the display of data in the view, this must also be edited to remove the deleted item.

What is the best way to manage this scenario?

Answer (score 4):

I can remove all entries for a list if I know what the starting name

e.g.

```
MyItems[0].Id
MyItems[0].Name
MyItems[1].Id
MyItems[1].Name
```

A static helper can be used as follows

```
ModelState.Remove_StartsWith("MyItems");
```

Although this will also remove any items with errors. Since the ModelState keys have a particular form : name[n].name - to remove only the one item matching the model item requires not only finding that item in ModelState but also managing the index numbers of the ModelState keys - probably creating a new ModelState with the updated key list in contiguous order

```
/// <summary>
/// Remove all entries where a key starts with a given value
/// This will remove list entries
/// </summary>
/// <param name="dic"></param>
/// <param name="startsWith"></param>
static public void Remove_StartsWith(this ModelStateDictionary dic, string startsWith)
{
    foreach (string key in dic.Keys.Where(k => k.StartsWith(startsWith)).ToList())
    {
        dic.Remove(key);
    }
}
```

Comment: for me it worked better if I use k.EndsWith